# restart java thread after join method

Tags: multithreading, join, kill-process

i want to know how to restart this thread
i kill the thread by using join method but i got this exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
the manager of the threads:

```
public void manage() {

    while(true)
    {
        thread1.start();
        try {
            thread1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        thread2.start();
        try {
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing a really odd thing - sequentially running two threads, waiting for each to terminate with join(), in a while(true) loop?  Why not start one thread, just once, whose run() method contains the while(true) and just sequentially calls the code from your thread1 and thread2?  No join(), no continual thread create/terminate/destroy.

Answer (score 5):

You can't restart a thread in Java. Once it's completed, it's done.

Instead, you should create a *new* `Thread` potentially using the same `Runnable`, and start the new thread. EDIT: Although you *could* potentially use the "old" `Thread` object as the `Runnable` for the new thread to run, I would avoid doing so if possible. I try to keep `Runnable` and `Thread` very separate; I view it as a design mistake that you can even create a `Thread` just by extending it, and that `Thread` implements `Runnable`.

Note that joining a thread *doesn't* kill it - it just waits for it to complete. They're very different operations. When one thread (X) joins another thread (Y), there's no indication within Y that anything is waiting for it to terminate - there isn't even a *hint* that it should try to stop.

Comment: @SLaks Not sure that it is such a good idea considering that a Thread is quite a heavy object...

Comment: @SLaks: Potentially, but I would try to avoid it. Will edit along those lines.

Comment: so how can i use join method on that case?

Comment: @user2625638: In what case?

Comment: @SLaks `new Thread(oldThread)` would work but it is not the cleanest way, I tried it more than two times the third time it failed, I had to replace it by `Runnable`

Answer (score 2):

A Java thread can only be executed once.

If you want to run it again, create a new `Thread` around the same `Runnable`.

Comment: @user2625638: The same way you call `join()` on any other thread.  However, if you start a thread and then immediately `join()` it, you aren't getting any benefit out of using the thread.

Comment: As I changed an important value (which made the `thread` stop at first) in the `runnable` class. Therefore I couldn't just use the same one. I had to reinstantiate the `runnable`, then create a new `Thread` on the new `runnable`.